# Error handling in BizTalk 2016 for content errors

Tags: error-handling, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We are developing an interface between two systems exposing set of REST interfaces.

On the consumer side, it can happen that the API call from the orchestration to the consumer app results in content error (eg. dictionary value not defined on the consumer side). Because the consumer doesn't expose all dictionary APIs, we have to escalate such a situation to the ops team, who can include missing dictionary value and re-trigger the message.

Problem is that our Biztalk developers say that it is not really possible to re-trigger the message that has been already sent to outbound queue.

Is this really the case? How can I re-trigger the message that already left the orchestration and was sent to the outbound queue?

Comment: From your question, it’s not clear who is consumer and api provider, can you explain it bit more and be specific

Comment: We have: application A, a provider, BizTalk in the middle, as a middleware, and application C as a consumer. BizTalk takes data elements from A and transmits it to C. C might raise a content error, when one of the attributes transmitted is not in the internal app dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this whole process, it really depends on how you design the solution. You have few options:

1. When escalating the error to ops team assuming in automated way from BizTalk, you can start a new orchestration instance with original message who waits on a retrigger request with missing data using a correlation I’d and then once request is submitted it can merge both and process it. This approach will keep a long running instance depending on how long it takes to get response from ops team.
2. Another option is to save the message before escalating to a database or somewhere else and then retrieve it using some correlation id on re-trigger workflow. This is kind of similar to first option except in this case you manage saving and retrieving message from a custom store vs BizTalk keeping it in spool, requires more dev effort but if your volume is very high of such instances you may want to do this
3. Let the ops team submit the whole request again if possible with missing data. This way you won’t need to maintain state in BizTalk.

There are probably other options based on yr specific need and design constraint you have. Hope this gives u a good start. This can certainly be done.